# HTML5 Range Slider

Tags: html

The following HTML5 code works in Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer 11

```
<input type=range min=0 max=200 value=0 id=fader step=1 onchange="outputFirstUpdate(value)" />
<label>£<output for=fader id=FirstAmount>0</output></label><br />
```

The problem in IE 11 is that the label is always 0 when the slider is moved.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What does outputFirstUpdate() do?

Comment: It calls this javascript                                              function outputFirstUpdate(first) {
document.querySelector('#FirstAmount').value = first;
} to get the selected slider value and it works fine apart from in IE

Comment: maybe IE does not support the output tag?

Comment: Seems still a bit buggy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241415/html5-number-input-field-step-attribute-broken-in-internet-explorer-10-and-inter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```js
function updateInput(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput').innerHTML=val; 
    }
```

```html
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateInput(this.value);">                                                       
    <p id="textInput"></p>
```