# Shocker, IE 11 has issues with number validation when the step attribute is used. Has anyone found a fix for this

Tags: javascript, html, validation, internet-explorer-11

So this may, or may not come as a shock to anyone, but the step validation is wonky in IE11

When using `step="0.001"` things stop working correctly when it tries to validate the number

```html
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <input type="number" min="-1000" max="1000" step="0.001">
        <button type="submit">t</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

With my example above if I enter, say, `1.111` it works as expected.  But certain numbers do not work.  For example 1.55, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3, 1.8, 2.8, 3.8

This is somewhat annoying.  If anyone has found a fix for this it would help me out.

Thanks

edit:
I guess my question may be similar to [HTML5 number input field step attribute broken in Internet Explorer 10 and Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241415/html5-number-input-field-step-attribute-broken-in-internet-explorer-10-and-inter) but considering that it does not have an answer it does not solve my issue in any way.  But thanks anyways BSMP

Comment: Sounds like a floating point rounding bug. I'd just validate in JS.

Comment: May have to come to that.  There is a lot of different pages with a lot of different steps, so am hoping for another solution, but may not have a choice

Comment: seems tedious but til you could find a proper solution just place a placeholder first then convert to float in back end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 number input field step attribute broken in Internet Explorer 10 and Internet Explorer 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241415/html5-number-input-field-step-attribute-broken-in-internet-explorer-10-and-inter)

Comment: I guess my question may be similar to HTML5 number input field step attribute broken in Internet Explorer 10 and Internet Explorer 11 but considering that it does not have an answer it does not solve my issue in any way. But thanks anyways @BSMP